# Bash pass variable as argument with quotes

Tags: linux, bash

Assume `./program` is a program that just prints out the parameters;

```
$ ./program "Hello there"
Hello there
```

How can I properly pass arguments with quotes in from a variable? I am trying to do this;

```
$ args='"Hello there"'  
$ echo ${args}  
"Hello there"  
$ ./program ${args}  
Hello there # This is 1 argument
```

but instead, when I go through a variable the quotes in `args` seem to be ignored so I get;

```
$ args='"Hello there"'
$ echo ${args}
"Hello there"
$ ./program ${args}
"Hello there" # This is 2 arguments
```

Is it possible to have bash treat the quotes as if I entered them myself in the first code block?

Comment: `./program "${args}"`

Comment: @redneb Tried that, it still treats it as 2 arguments (`"Hello` and `there"`)

Comment: Then `program` is broken.

Comment: How do you know (or why do you think) `program` is treating the expansion of `"$args"` as two arguments?

Comment: @chepner My comment is wrong. It does treat it as a single arg, but for some reason when you go through a variable that arg is `"Hello there"` and when you go through command line the arg is `Hello There`. Can't figure out how to get around those quotes (see my comments in the answer below)

Comment: When you write `args="Hello there"`, the quotes aren't part of the variable. They are syntax to make sure the entire string is assigned to `args`, not just `Hello`. `args=Hello\ there` is equivalent; the space is escaped to avoid ending the assignment early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you got `program` from, but it appears that it's broken. Here's a correct way to write it in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in "$@"; do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

This will print each argument in a separate line to make them easier to distinguish (it will of course have a problem with arguments that contain a line break, but we will not pass such an argument).

After you have saved the above as `program` and gave it the execute permission, try this:

```
$ args='"Hello there"'
$ ./program "${args}"
"Hello there"
```

whereas

```
$ args='"Hello there"'
$ ./program ${args}
"Hello
there"
```

Comment: Gotcha, but the problem is if I write it out by hand I get different results. `./program "Hello there"` is one argument without the quotes while `./program "${args}"` is one argument with the quotes. Understand what I am getting at? The former produces `Hello there` while the latter I get `"Hello there"`, they aren't the same arguments

Comment: Try this `./program '"Hello There"'` then.

Comment: I need to get rid of the quotes in the variable form, not the other way around. So that I can run `./program "${args}"` and get the exact same output as I would with `./program "Hello there"`

Comment: If the variable includes the quotes, you have to modify the variable, or  not include them in the variable in the first place.

Comment: The idea is that I need to load arguments from a file. So if a file contains `"Argument 1" Two Three` then calling `./program` should give me `[ Argument 1, Two, Three ]` as the arguments like I would get when I went directly through the command line. That doesn't seem to be possible through this method you described

Comment: @user2249516 - you are reading and incorrectly assigning the values from file to the variables. You should assign those values to an array then pass the array to program as `./program "${var[@]}"` then you won't have issues with the quotes within the array because it was never in the array in the first place. So work on the reader and passers instead of finding a workaround on program.

Comment: @user2249516 In that case, probably the easiest solution is to use `xargs`: `echo "$args" | xargs ./program`. Or use `eval`: `eval './program "$args"'`.