# Bash how to include a command that has quotation marks as a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

In my bash script, in several places I need to run the command

`rsync [stuff] --exclude={"/mnt/*","/proc/*"} [source] [destination]`

To avoid typing out the whole list, I want to pack the option `--exclude={"/mnt/*","/proc/*"}` into a variable called `EXCLUDES` such that I can type in my script:

`rsync [stuff] "$EXCLUDES" [source] [destination]`

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash pass variable as argument with quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583838/bash-pass-variable-as-argument-with-quotes)

Comment: `EXCLUDES='--exclude={"/mnt/*","/proc/*"}'`

Comment: There is no problem: `$EXCLUDES` can expand into something which contains quotation marks; these are not processed in relation to the quotes around `"$EXCLUDES"`.  The `$VAR` syntax cannot perpetrate a "close quote injection attack" against the surrounding syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
EXCLUDES=(
  --exclude="/mnt/*"
  --exclude="/proc/*"
)
rsync [stuff] "${EXCLUDES[@]}" [source] [destination]
```

or a here-doc with the `--exclude-from` option:

```
rsync [stuff] --exclude-from - [source] [destination] <<EOF
/mnt/proc/*
/proc/*
EOF
```

I would recommend against using brace expansion in a script. Your text editor should make it easy to quickly duplicate repeated strings, and the the resulting script will be more readable. Brace expansions are intended for interactive use.