# bash script doesn't work with variables

Tags: bash, sed, tr

Given a specific date, I want to query and download data. The data is in format `2018-04-22` but the script takes data in the form of `2018 04 22`, so I am doing the following:

```
 #!/bin/sh

filename=extract_dates.dat

line=1
totline=`wc -l < $filename`

while [ $line -le $totline ]
do
    date=`sed -n -e ''"$line"'p' $filename | awk '{print $line}'`
    startdate=$(echo $date | tr "-" " ") # ex: 2018-04-22 --> 2018 04 22
    plusone=`echo ${startdate:8:2}`      # extracts the last 2 digits from date. so in this example 22 
    enddate=${startdate:0:8}`expr $plusone + 1` # plus 1 .. so now it's 23
    echo \'$startdate\'    # '2018 04 22'
    echo \'$enddate\'      # '2018 04 23'

    mkdir $date
    cd $date

    # query and download data
   ../prog_access.sh -StartDate \'$startdate\' -EndDate \'$enddate\'
```

The script runs but the output result is null.
However, this works perfectly fine from the command line:

```
   ../prog_access.sh -StartDate '2018 04 22' -EndDate '2018 04 23'
```

What's wrong? I know the problem is from the dates but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @rkta: as shown in the question, the `#!` has a leading space so it will have no effect.  You are right though, the `#!` is wrong.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with `bash` when you appear to be using `sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `"$startdate"` instead of `\'$startdate\'` in your script.

```
../prog_access.sh -StartDate "$startdate" -EndDate "$enddate"
```

`\'2018 04 22\'` is not the same as `'2018 04 22'`. Passing this string as command argument in the script has the same effect as typing

```
../prog_access.sh -StartDate \'2018 04 22\' -EndDate \'2018 04 23\'
```

in a command line and this approach causes `StartDate` argument to be read as `'2018`.

Also, you cannot use `'$startdate'` in your script as it will not replace the variable value.

You can look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583838/bash-pass-variable-as-argument-with-quotes) question to get more familiar with how does bash passes arguments from variables and how are them read in various cases.